# Is there API for email account setup in iOS

Tags: ios, api, email

MFMailComposeViewController for compose the email.
But what's the API for setting up email account?

Comment: In addition to what CodeFi said, I believe if there isn't an email account set up when you call the MFMailComposeViewController it will prompt you to go to settings and configure one. Unrelated but the Twitter API does this as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFMailComposeViewController does not include such a method.  Applications are expected to call `+canSendMail` to query if an account has been set up, and gracefully transition if it has not.