# How to get mail configuration information if allowed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, sendmail

Hi I am using SMTP server framework to send mails.

```
NSArray *arr1 = [testMsg.fromEmail componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
NSArray *arr2 = [[arr1 objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ([arr2 containsObject:@"gmail"]) {
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
}
else if ([arr2 containsObject:@"yahoo"]) {
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
}
else if ([arr2 containsObject:@"hotmail"] || [arr2 containsObject:@"live"]) {
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.live.com";
}
else
{
    NSString *smtpRelay = [[NSString alloc]init];
    smtpRelay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"smtp.%@.com",[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]];
    testMsg.relayHost = smtpRelay;
}

testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
testMsg.login = @"mycompanyUserName@mycompany.com";
testMsg.password = @"********";
testMsg.subject = @"This is the email subject line";
testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!
```

If i want to send a mail from my office ID or other i want to fetch mail info automatically that is configured in MAIL application.

So That i can send a mail from configured mail (in device).is it possible to get the info like this ...if allowed ....please help me ......I don't want to user to enter id and password...Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't be done. There is no public API that gives you any information about the mail accounts a user has setup.

Comment: Oh.Thanks for the reply.Can we get share with mail option type.So that i can open the action sheet to configure/login the mail according to their accout type.

Comment: No. There is no public API related in any way to working with email servers.

Comment: oh cool.But few apps asking the permissions to use personal info ...an d it will send mails to it right..

Comment: If not possible.How can i send mails by using my office account ?

Comment: What do you mean by "my office account"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there API for email account setup in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952610/is-there-api-for-email-account-setup-in-ios)